# Windows powershell is not printing emoji

Tags: python, powershell, terminal, emoji

I am trying print folder emoji `U+1F4C1` in powershell using python. According to this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-emojis/) i wrote code `print("\U0001F4C1")` which works perfectly while running inside the pycharm but when i try i run it from it terminal all i get is two boxes with question mark. See the image for
[the output i mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUgm3.png).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [**Windows Terminal**](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N0DX20HK701), it's printing

Comment: I was using windows powershell, thats why emoji is not printing for me. I didnt even know about windows terminal. But now i am going to change to that

Answer (score 0):

Windows terminal don't support Unicode printed In terminal try to print It in a text editor(Pycharm, Visual studio code). The Output will be printed in the text editor terminal . For Printing Emoji in windows 10 press Windows key and Period key (".")  or full stop.

Comment: Thanks for the help, didnt know before that cmd or windows powershell can't print emoji